# CLASSPATH, Java Buld Path (eclipse), and WEB-INF\LIB : what to use, when, and why?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jar, classpath

I recently switched to J2EE from .NET, and am confused about where to put JAR files.  I know that the CLASSPATH, WEB-INF, and Eclipse's Java Web Path are all places where JARs can be stored, but I'm confused about which folder to use, when, and why.

First off, we have the CLASSPATH.  I usually set this by going into "Environment Variables" inside "My Computer."  I know that this is the default place where the Java compiler looks for JAR files.  When I add a folder or a JAR to my CLASSPATH environment variable, why is it ignored by Eclipse, the Java compiler, and the web server?

Also, I know that WEB-INF\LIB is a place where you can put JAR files that your web app is going to use.  However, I've put JARs in WEB-INF\LIB only to have them be ignored.  In what situations should I put JARs into WEB-INF\LIB folder?  How do I get Eclipse or the web server to notice them?

So far, the only thing that works for me is to actually change the Java Build Path for an Eclipse project.  I'll select the JARs I need and hit "Add External JARs."  Most of the time when I do this, Eclipse will recognize my JARs and read the classes therein.  However, I've run into a bunch of weird random errors while doing this (mostly having to do with dependencies, I think).  For some reason, I just get the feeling that this isn't the right way to do things, and that I'm missing some vital piece of information.  When should I be manually Adding External JARs inside Eclipse, and when should I be doing things differently?  How come Eclipse's Java Build Path doesn't seem to know about the folders in my CLASSPATH environment variable?

Really, I would just like to gain a better understanding of the CLASSPATH, Eclipse's Java Build Path, and the WEB-INF/LIB folder -- the purposes they serve, the relationships between them, and where I should be putting my JARs in various situations.  I would appreciate any advice you could give me, or any articles that you could recommend.

Thank you.

Comment: Oh, and one other question -- if my web application requires a certain JAR, do I need to add that JAR to the Run Configuration as well as the project's Build Path?  Are the Run Configuration and Build Path always completely separate things, or does one ever affect the other?

Comment: (and yes, it is assumed that I am running my web project from Eclipse)

Comment: How can we do this for EAR/lib pages ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753457/jasper-reports-package-net-sf-jasperreports-engine-does-not-exist-exception-in Regards,

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `CLASSPATH` you set in your environment affects only standalone Java applications, i.e. ones you run from a command prompt or an icon. As you've noticed, Eclipse ignores this. It sets up its own per-project classpaths.

`javac` and `java`, if called from the command prompt, should/may honor this path, but it's no longer considered great practice to do this. It's turned out that every app needs its own set of stuff, so a global CLASSPATH isn't really doing any of them any good. Modern practice is to simply specify the classpath with the `-cp` option on the command line for `javac` or `java`.

A standalone Web Application server will also set up its own classpath. From the command line or GUI, WebAppServers are usually started by a script (`.BAT` or `.sh`) that sets up a classpath using `-cp`. Tomcat has a directory called `common` or `common/lib` where it expects to see libraries that should be available the the server and all programs running under it. But you will generally not need/want to mess with this, as it's customaries for applications to provide their own library collectons in `WEB-INF/lib`.

So for a Web app, you'd put your varous jars into the `lib` directory, under `WEB-INF`, assuming Eclipse pre-builds such a directory structure for you.

All the libs you need also need to be made known to Eclipse. In the Project Explorer, I select the whole slew of them at once, right-click and select `Build Path | add to build path`. That's easier than messing with Eclipse's project build path manually.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that Eclipse will recognize all `jar` under `WEB-INF/lib` and we don't need to add them to build path. It is necessary only for those `jar` in another path.

Answer (score 11):

Java has a long history and experience has shown that some ideas were good and some were bad.

The CLASSPATH environment variable was the initial way to tell the Java machine where to locate classes from your program, and works reasonably well for command line programs.  It was rapidly found that this should not be a global thing (as that tend to mess things up in the long run) but a per-program thing.  This could be done by creating a wrapper script/BAT-file which sets the variable and runs the Java machine.

All was well, then people wanted to write web server stuff in Java.  The Servlet API was created where a web application is a stand-alone unit - this resulted in that the CLASSPATH for *each* web application *is* the unpacked files under WEB-INF/classes plus the jar-files under WEB-INF/lib.   And only that.  This means the global CLASSPATH variable is ignored.  This has been found to be a *VERY* good thing, so the concept has migrated elsewhere.

For instance a "executable jar" (which Eclipse calls a "runnable jar") which is invoked with "java -jar foobar.jar" contains the complete classpath INSIDE the Jar in a special manifest file.   Java Web Start which is used to start java programs from a web server explicily lists the full classpath in the configuration file on the server.

But, to get you started.  If you want to write a Java web application:

1. Get the Eclipse *Java EE* version.
2. Create a new Dynamic Web Project e.g. named foobar.
3. Drag and drop (or copy/paste) the jar files you need in foobar/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
4. Create a new file named foobar/WebContent/index.jsp.   In the blank file type `<h1>Hello World <%= new java.util.Date() %></h1>`
5. Right click in editor for index.jsp, choose Run -> Run on Server, and choose the Basic -> J2EE preview at localhost server, and Finish.

A browser window will now open, either in a browser or inside Eclipse which will render your JSP-page.   You can change the JSP-page, save it with Ctrl-S and reload the browser window to see the changes.

Comment: @SanderVerhagen I do not understand your comment.  The question is clearly in the context of a web container (which usually run in Java SE).

Comment: @SanderVerhagen No. All the support for anything related to servlets and above is in the Plugins coming preinstalled with EE (which you can install from Marketplace for SE). You can do plain WARs anyway without EJB.

Comment: The simplest way to get started with a web app these days is to use the Netbeans+Glassfish bundle.

Answer (score 4):

> Also, I know that WEB-INF\LIB is a place where you can put JAR files that your web app is going to use. However, I've put JARs in WEB-INF\LIB only to have them be ignored. In what situations should I put JARs into WEB-INF\LIB folder? How do I get Eclipse or the web server to notice them?

The **real** problem you have here is likely that you didn't got [*Eclipse for Java **EE** developers*](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and/or that you just created a generic *Java Project* instead of a *Dynamic Web Project* and built up the necessary folder structure yourself.

If you create a *Dynamic Web Project* in *Eclipse for Java EE developers*, then Eclipse will automagically add any libraries in `WEB-INF/lib` to the *build path*. The *build path* is roughly said just the classpath which is been used in both compiletime and runtime. With other words: just drop the 3rd party JAR's in there, really nothing more needs to be done.

Note that Java is case sensitive, thus it should be really called `WEB-INF/lib`, not `WEB-INF/LIB`. But anyway, if you create a *Dynamic Web Project*, then Eclipse will just automagically generate the correct folder/file structure for you.

As said by others, ignore the `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable. It is *only* used by javac.exe/java.exe and even then *only* when you do **not** specify any of the `-cp`, `-classpath` or -`jar` arguments. In real world this environment variable is seldom used, it is just some convenience for starters (and unfortunately also the most confusing one, they should never have invented it).

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with web applications, /WEB-INF/lib is the portable place to put JARs.  This is where <s>web servers</s> servlet containers expect to find an application's jar files.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse requires you to specify the path to your libraries, jar files (on Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab). This can be found on the .classpath project file.

Usually you have the JRE libs on its path (which would be on your classpath too), so adding the libs to the classpath and updating eclipse build path would work.

The WEB-INF directory should be the place that contains necessary information for your web application.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an Eclipse expert, but I think that your problem can be answered like this:

1) CLASSPATH is an environment variable that is read in when you launch java programs and is used by classloader to figure out where the classes are placed.

I would modify the CLASSPATH variable only in the case when you are launching an java program from a script, as this allows you to conveniently launch a program and make sure that the classes are found. This would not be the case for you, as you are developing the web application.

2) WEB-INF/lib is the directory under which the web application container's classloader (like tomcat or glassfish) looks into if your web application needs to resolve a class. So you put there the classes that are used in your web application.

Some IDE's do include the libraries/.jar files that you are using in a project automatically to the package.

3) Eclipse library/classpath resolving during the development time. I would assume, but apologies for assuming, as one really shouldn't do this ;), that you can define a library (add external .jar files to projects) and autocomplete/all the other interesting features should start working with this, as you basically make those classes visible for the IDE with that activity. I also would assume that you can then mark those libraries to be automatically added to the web projects etc., by the IDE.

In general a good reading about how classes are found during execution is [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/findingclasses.html) (it's a sun's official documentation). Also a good place to read about this is the ClassLoader class documentation.

Comment: (1) No, Eclipse wants libraries explicitly made known via the project's build path. (2) Sun's class loader documentation is authoritative, complete and instructional, but when it comes to working in an IDE, it's only useful as background info. Eclipse works hard to abstract these issues for the user; while generally beneficial, this can be confusing for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

Taken together the comments helped me as well.  I had added all the jena .jars to the build path from eclipse but that wasn't sufficient.  Following suggestion to "add to WEB-INF/lib" it seemed intuitive to drag from libraries folder to WEB-INF (from within eclipse), but that didn't work.  Nor did copying the .jars to WEB-INF.  I eventually drag-and-dropped from the windows desktop to the WEB-INF lib folder in Eclipse, and that fixed the problem.  It would be nice if any .jars added to the build path were automatically copied to WEB-INF lib by Eclipse.  In case it matters, this was eclipse EE IDE, Indigo release, on windows 7.